# Geting an error saying Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to replace categorical variables with numbers for scaling purpose; where my dataset is named as bank but gives the above error..Can some one help
Below is my code

```
newstruct= {"job":{"blue-collar":1,"management":2,"technician":3,"admin":4,"services":5,"retired":6,"self-employed":7,
                  "entrepreneur":8,"unemployed":9,"housemaid":10,"student":11,"unknown":12},
            "marital":{"married":2,"single":1,"divorced":3},
            "education":{"secondary":2,"tertiary":3,"primary":1},
            "default":{"yes":1,"no":0},
            "housing":{"yes":1,"no":0},
            "y":{"yes":1,"no":0},
            "poutcome":{"unknown":4,"failure":2,"other":3,"success":1}} 


bank=bank.replace(newstruct)
```

Comment: I believe it'd be easier to answer the question if you provided more context.

Comment: this is to replace categorical variables to ordinal values  in the data, so have used to codes with numbers 1,2, etc...and finally used replaced function but gives the error for conversion

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear, you need to convert 'str' into an integer using a function like `int("0")`.

In order for us to help, you need to offer us more information, for example where the comparison happens. And what exactly the code and error are.

Hope this helps.